# How to make sure input is an ODE

Tags: differential-equations, syntax

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why this isn't an ordinary differential equation.

```
Cto == 3.5; kd1 == 0.25; ke2 == 0.1; kf3 == 5.0;
s = NDSolve[{
Derivative[1][FA][V] == -kd1*Cto^3*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FB[V]/Fto[V])^2
                          - 3 ke2*Cto^2*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FlowD[V]/Fto[V]),

Derivative[1][FB][V] == -2 kd1*Cto^3*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FB[V]/Fto[V])^2
                          - kf3*Cto^2*(FB[V]/Fto[V])*(FC[V]/Fto[V])^2, 

Derivative[1][FC][V] == kd1*Cto^3*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FB[V]/Fto[V])^2
                          + ke2*Cto^2*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FlowD[V]/Fto[V])
                            - 2 kf3*Cto^3*(FB[V]/Fto[V])*(FC[V]/Fto[V])^2,

Derivative[1][FlowD][V] == kd1*Cto^3*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FB[V]/Fto[V])^2
                             - 2 ke2*Cto^2*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FlowD[V]/Fto[V])
                               + kf3*Cto^3*(FB[V]/Fto[V])*(FC[V]/Fto[V])^2,

Derivative[1][FE][V] == ke2*Cto^2*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FlowD[V]/Fto[V]),

Derivative[1][FF][V] == kf3*Cto^3*(FB[V]/Fto[V])*(FC[V]/Fto[V])^2,

Fto[V] == FA[V] + FB[V] + FC[V] + FlowD[V] + FE[V] + FF[V], 

FA[0] == 0, FB[0] == 0, FC[0] == 0, FlowD[0] == 0, FE[0] == 0, FF[0] == 0, Fto[V] == 0},

{FA[V], FB[V], FC[V], FlowD[V], FE[V], FF[V], Fto[V]}, {V, 0, 50}]
```

Now the problem is that it's over specified.

Thanks!

Comment: For starters, you are trying to sole an equation numerically but some constants are not defined and you're missing the initial conditions.

Comment: (1) By `k3`  you probably meant `kf3`. (2)  Initialize the parameters (`Cto, kd1, ke2, kf3` ) before  using them., i.e., use `Cto = 3.5; kd1 = 0.25; ke2 = 0.1; kf3 = 5.0;` before `NDSolve[...]`. (3) Add `Fto[V]` to the list of functions in the second argument: i.e. use `{FA[V], FB[V], FC[V], FD[V], fFE[V], FF[V], Fto[V]}`

Comment: I did all of the suggestions above, and now the system is overdetermined.

Comment: You know what that means, do you?

Comment: It's saying I have fewer dependent variables than equations, but I have 7 of each.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[Cto, kd1, ke2, kf3, FA, FB, FC, FD, FE, FF, Fto, V]

Cto = 3.5; kd1 = 0.25; ke2 = 0.1; kf3 = 5.0;
```

Note: `=` (not `==`) in the line above.

```
s = NDSolve[{FA'[V] == -kd1*Cto^3*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FB[V]/Fto[V])^2 - 
     3 ke2*Cto^2*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FD[V]/Fto[V]), 
   FB'[V] == -2 kd1*Cto^3*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FB[V]/Fto[V])^2 - 
     kf3*Cto^2*(FB[V]/Fto[V])*(FC[V]/Fto[V])^2, 
   FC'[V] == kd1*Cto^3*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FB[V]/Fto[V])^2 + 
     ke2*Cto^2*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FD[V]/Fto[V]) - 
     2 kf3*Cto^3*(FB[V]/Fto[V])*(FC[V]/Fto[V])^2, 
   FD'[V] == kd1*Cto^3*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FB[V]/Fto[V])^2 - 
     2 ke2*Cto^2*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FD[V]/Fto[V]) + 
     kf3*Cto^3*(FB[V]/Fto[V])*(FC[V]/Fto[V])^2, 
   FE'[V] == ke2*Cto^2*(FA[V]/Fto[V])*(FD[V]/Fto[V]), 
   FF'[V] == kf3*Cto^3*(FB[V]/Fto[V])*(FC[V]/Fto[V])^2, 
   Fto[V] == FA[V] + FB[V] + FC[V] + FD[V] + FE[V] + FF[V]}, 
   {FA[V], FB[V], FC[V], FD[V], FE[V], FF[V], Fto[V]}, {V, 0, 50}];

Plot[Evaluate[{FA[V], FB[V], FC[V], FD[V], FE[V], FF[V]} /. s], {V, 0,  5},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Purple, Cyan}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"FA[V]", "FB[V]", "FC[V]", "FD[V]", "FE[V]", "FF[V]"}, 
 BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Fto[V] /. s], {V, 0, 5},
 PlotStyle -> Brown, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"Fto[V]"}, 
 BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notes on your code:

1. By `k3` you probably meant `kf3`.
2. Initialize the parameters (`Cto, kd1, ke2, kf3`) before using them, using `Set (=)`, not `Equal (==)`.
3. Add `Fto[V]` to the list of functions in the second argument.

Comment: Perfect, I added the initial conditions and it works like a charm. What exactly did you change? I can't really tell. Thanks again!!

Comment: @JosephKessler, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se. Re "what exactly..." :  used `=` instead of `==` in the initialization line.